# Import CSV/TSV into plain sheet in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers, import, csv

When I open a CSV/TSV in numbers it is imported into the default template, where the first row and the A-column are "headers". Most of the time I open such files the first row and A-column just plain data like any other cell that shouldn't be treated differently.

How can I make Numbers open CSV/TSV smarter than its default behaviour?

I can see a couple of different options:

- Open the file into a plain sheet where row 1 and column A don't differ from the other rows and columns
- Insert the data from cell B1 or B2 and down (in case you want to add a header row and/or a "header" column).

---

Desktop iWork, current version of iWork and Ventura.